# How to use NSTimer with data from NSURL pass to NSXMLParser display in TableView

Tags: tableview, nstimer, nsxmlparser, nsurl

How to use NSTimer with data from NSURL pass to NSXMLParser display in TableView

I have application display data from web server by PHP gen' to XML

In my xcode i use NSURL for connect to PHP file (in web server)
and use NSXMLParser to read XML data put value to array
and final display on TableView

I want to see data in TableView live update or update every x time

I think i can use NSTimer but i don't know how i can
where i can put NSTimer to the code in xcode

Answer (score 0):

In short, something like:

```
// Schedule a timer repeating every 2 seconds
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self.tableView
                               selector:@selector(reloadData)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Longer version:

You need to call -doParse from a timer, fetch data, do parsing, and reload the data.

In order not to block main thread, you must **NOT** call `[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL]` from main thread.

Instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
      NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
      ...
      // finish parsing
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [tableView reloadData];
      });
});
```

And call `-doParse` with a NSTimer from -viewDidLoad :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(doParse)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Further reading:
WWDC 2012 Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS.

Comment: in my code http://www.vasuta.com/ios/MyLoxFile.zip ... file "MyLoxFileTVContoller.m" i move line  36 to 79 into dispatch_async right? ... where i put dispatch_async in my project?

Comment: http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/480533_522854577730924_988295295_n.jpg

Comment: You have to at least uncomment one of the two `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: if i use [self.tableView reloadData]; tableview it's not show in my view